# Excel: Use values in a sheet as index to list in a different sheet and replace values in the first sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an XL file with some data to be manipulated. I think I will need to use a VB script to do this - but perhaps there is a simpler way with a formula. Just the same, could someone point out BOTH ways of achieving the following?

I have a column of numeric values (ID) in Sheet 1.
I want to use each ID as an index to lookup a list in Sheet 2.
Sheet 2 has two columns
First column is the index and Second column is the Text String
e.g.

1 Apple

2 Orange

3 Pear

What I want is to replace the column of IDs in sheet 1 with the looked up text string from Sheet 2!

Thats all...
Please help!

Comment: Does your column of ID's in sheet 1 match the row number?

Comment: No. In sheet 1, the column of IDs are random. Also there can be duplicates. But in Sheet 2, the column 1 of the index list is in ascending order starting with 0.

Comment: If you want "Replacing" to be done then you have to use VBA/VBScript. However you can use Vlookup() in Column 3 to find what that ID holds so that you can later copy paste those value in Col A

Comment: Use `vlookup` in Sheet 1, and paste-as-value to replace your origin column.

Comment: @Siddarth, yes I do need the "replacing" to be done. Would you or someone on this forum be willing to show me what the VBA/script will look like? I am new at this.

Comment: This should get you started ;) http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ Alternatively, you could use Excel Formula `Vlookup` in VBA/VBScript to perform the above task. I would recommend giving it a try and then showing us what you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: Thanks guys! I am starting with Vlookup and this has at least got me moving forward, while I try to understand the "find" approach as well. I am really a newbie at VB.  @Siddarth - Thanks for the tutorial site! I will post back.

Answer (score 2):

Not a tough situation there. Here are some solutions...

**With VBA:**

I know you said you're a little new with VB so I tried to explain each line as I went along. Also, the code is free-handed so forgive me if I left an error in there somewhere.

```
Sub replaceData()

dim i as integer, j as integer 'These are just some variables we'll use later.
dim sheetOne as worksheet, sheetTwo as worksheet, myWb as workbook
dim myData as string, myId as string

set myWB = excel.activeworkbook 'These three lines set your workbook/sheet variables.
set sheetOne = myWB.worksheets("Old Data")
set sheetTwo = myWB.worksheets("New Data")

for i = 1 to sheetTwo.usedrange.rows.count 'This loops through the rows on your second sheet.
   myId = sheetTwo.cells(i,1).value 'This assigns the value for your id and the data on your second sheet.
   myData = sheetTwo.cells(i,2).value
   for j = 1 to sheetOne.usedrange.rows.count 'This loops through the rows on your first sheet.
      if sheetOne.cells(j,1).value = myId then 'This checks each row for a matching id value.
         sheetOne.cells(j,1).value = myData 'This replaces that id with the data we got from the second sheet.
      end if
   next j
next i

end sub
```

**With an Excel formula:**

1. Place the following formula in cell C1 of the first worksheet (the
   sheet with the IDs you will be replacing). ****Note** that you will
   have to replace the "InsertSheetTwoNameHere" portion with the name
   of your second sheet (don't remove those single quotes though). Also
   note you will need to replace the "1000" with the number of the last
   used row in sheet two.

   =vlookup(A1,’InsertSheetTwoNameHere’!$A$1:$B$1000,2,FALSE)
2. Next simply drag the handle on the cell that makes it copy itself
   (whatever the heck it's called) all the way down to the end of your
   range.
3. Next, copy those cells and then paste them over the IDs using the
   *Values Only* setting.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Your vlookup formula helped me solve a similar problem. Thanks!